Keep "dracut-initqueue" from timing out, Fedora Linux
So, recently I've made a switch to Fedora for my main OS (from NixOS), and.. So far it's been good, but one note is.. I kind of have a hefty amount of encryption to ensure my data is safe. It's far too much, and I know it well, but it's the thing that keeps me able to sleep at night, and I've heard it all before -- so please, do not try to talk me out of this. However, I do have one problem with all of it -- On boot, Dracut(?) [dracut-initqueue] enters emergency mode, because it's timed out -- due to the length of the boot time. The boot time is approximately 10 minutes, of which I typically just wait out by going to get some coffee, come back and it's done. So it's not impeding on my life -- but with that said, I have no idea how to get rid of this emergency mode -- It does say "Control D" to continue, but yeah. The second wish I have, is for Plymouth to continue, instead of exiting out (timing out). Are these two things possible, by chance?
